# Centering \newtcblisting

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, minted, tcblisting

Continuing with my book in xelatex, I could't solve how to center a tcblisting.

Here is my (i hope this time), MWE:

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = xelatex
% !TEX spellcheck = es_ES
% !TEX root = draft.tex

\documentclass[a4]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{codebggray}{HTML}{ffffff}
\definecolor{codebordergray}{RGB}{200,200,200} 

\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=codebggray]}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{mdframed}}

% Tamaño y color del número de línea
\renewcommand{\theFancyVerbLine}{\ttfamily \textcolor[rgb]{0.4,0.4,0.4}{\large {\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}}}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,xparse,hooks,many,minted}

\tcbset{
    mysource/.style={
        enhanced,
        enlarge top initially by=5mm,
        enlarge bottom finally by=5mm,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        sharp corners,
        rounded corners=north,
        center title,
        box align=center,  % <-- Tried to center this way (didn't work)
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=8pt,
        bottom=8pt,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        fontupper=\small,
        arc=4pt,
        outer arc=4pt,
        leftupper=5mm,
        width=0.9\linewidth,
        title={#1},
        overlay={%
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}  
                \fill[gray!25] ([yshift=1pt]frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=6mm]frame.north west);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}
        }
    }
}

% Replace "sourcebox" with "psourcebox" in case you want to try the code 
% that is commented below the following definition.
\newtcblisting{sourcebox}[1][]{
    mysource={\color{black}#1},
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=bash,
    colback=codebggray,
    colframe=codebordergray,
    listing only,
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    minted options = {
        linenos, 
        breaklines=true, 
        breakbefore=., 
        numbersep=2mm
    },
    overlay unbroken app = {%
        \begin{tcbcliptitle}
            \node[
            anchor     = north west,
            inner ysep = 1.75mm,
            inner xsep = 2mm
            ] at (frame.north west){\color{black}\Large\faCode};
        \end{tcbcliptitle},
        \node[anchor=north west,
        minimum size=10pt,
        draw=codebordergray,
        fill=codebordergray] at ([xshift=-11pt,yshift=11pt]frame.south east)
        {\ };
    },
    overlay first app = {%
        \begin{tcbcliptitle}
            \node[
            anchor     = north west,
            inner ysep = 1.75mm,
            inner xsep = 2mm
            ] at (frame.north west){\color{black}\Large\faCode};
        \end{tcbcliptitle}
    },
    overlay last app = {%
        \node[anchor=north west,
        minimum size=10pt,
        draw=codebordergray,
        fill=codebordergray] at ([xshift=-11pt,yshift=11pt]frame.south east)
        {\ };
    }
}

% Tried to center with this, it gave me an error.
%\newenvironment{sourcebox}[1][]
%{\begin{figure}[h]\centering\begin{psourcebox}[#1]}
%        {\end{psourcebox}\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{sourcebox}[\texttt{while-do-done}]
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$OPCION" != 5 ]; do
    echo " Listar archivos"
    echo " Ver directorio de trabajo"
    echo " Crear directorio"
    echo " Crear usuario"
    echo " Salir"
    read -p "Ingrese una opción: " OPCION

    case $OPCION in
    1) ls;;
    2) pwd;;
    3) read -p "Nombre del directorio: " DIRECTORIO
    mkdir $DIRECTORIO;;
    4) if id | grep uid=0; then
    read -p "Nombre del usuario: " NOMBREUSUARIO
    useradd $NOMBREUSUARIO
    else
    echo "Se necesitan permisos de root"
    fi
    ;;

    5);;

    *) echo "Opción ingresada invalida, intente de nuevo"
    ;;
    esac

done

    exit 0
\end{sourcebox}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know how, but somehow, this site surpressed the salutation. I wasn't tried to be impolite. Sorry.

Comment: Add `center` (page 88 in tcolorbox documentation) to `sourcebox` definition, but do it after fixing its width (i.e. after `mysource={\color{black}#1}`)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.